# How to test curried function that accept a dispatch for useReducer

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I have this single-line function

```
export const makeReducerSetState = dispatch => type => payload =>
  dispatch({ type, payload });
```

and this is how we call in the relative hook, where we are using useReducer

```
  const wrapReducerDispatch = makeReducerSetState(stateDispatch);
  const setSelectedSteps = wrapReducerDispatch(
    EDITION_MODAL_REDUCER_TYPES.SET_SELECTED_STEPS
  );
```

and after we call normally the action

```
const handleNext = useCallback(() => {
    setSelectedSteps({
      selectedIndex: selectedStep.selectedIndex + 1,
    });
  }, [selectedStep]);
```

I can't understand how can I test the first single-line function using Jest.
Literally, I tried to see several posts about curried function and reducer but I wasn't able to find a case like this one, can someone help me to understand?

How can I test this function down below ?

```
export const makeReducerSetState = dispatch => type => payload =>
  dispatch({ type, payload });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`redux-mock-store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-mock-store)

> this library is designed to test the action-related logic

`redux-mock-store` saves all the dispatched actions inside the store instance. You can get all the actions by calling `store.getActions()`. Finally, you can use any assertion library to test the payload.

E.g.

```
export const makeReducerSetState = (dispatch) => (type) => (payload) => dispatch({ type, payload });
```

```
import { makeReducerSetState } from '.';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const middlewares = [];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('75334107', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const initialState = {};
    const store = mockStore(initialState);
    const actionType = 'EDITION_MODAL_REDUCER_TYPES.SET_SELECTED_STEPS';
    makeReducerSetState(store.dispatch)(actionType)(1);
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual([{ type: actionType, payload: 1 }]);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75334107/index.test.ts (7.908 s)
  75334107
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.668 s, estimated 10 s
```

Comment: Holy Man, thank you! I was still thinking on how to test it, really appreciate your effort and clear answer.